# Strange vanishing of CR in strings coming from a copy of a file's content passed to raw_input()

Tags: python, copy-paste, carriage-return, raw-input

Trying to clear up the reasons of what seemed to be a bug, I finally bumped into a weird behaviour of the **raw_input()** function in Python 2.7:

it removes the **CR** characters of pairs **CR LF** from only the strings that result from a manual copy (via the clipboard) of a file's content. The strings passed to **raw_input()** that are copies of a display of identical strings than the former ones don't loose their **CR** characters. 
The alone **CR** chars remain untouched in all the cases. A **CR** (carriage return) is a **\r** character.

To be clearer than with a muddled description, here's a code describing what must be done to observe the fact, whose orders need only to be executed.

The point is in the **Text** object: it has 7 characters instead of the 8 that were passed to **raw_input()** to create **Text**.

To verifiy that the argument passed to **raw_input()** had really 8 characters, I created another file **PASTED.txt** with the same argument. It is indeed an awkward task to be sure of something in this problem, as the copying in a *Notepad++* window showed me: all sorts of ends of lines (\r , \n , \r\n) appear as **CR LF** at the extremities of the lines in such a window.

Ctrl-A to select the whole data of a file is recommended.

I am in the perplexity of wondering if I did a mistake of coding or comprehension, or if it is a real feature of Python.

I hope commentaries and light from you.

```
with open('PRIM.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write('A\rB\nC\r\nD')
print "  1) A file with name 'PRIM.txt' has just been created with content A\\rB\\nC\\r\\nD"
raw_input("  Open this file and copy manually its CONTENT in the clipboard.\n"+\
          "    --when done, press Enter to continue-- ")


print "\n  2) Paste this CONTENT in a Notepad++ window "+\
      "     and see the symbols at the extremities of the lines."
raw_input("    --when done, press Enter to continue-- ")


Text = raw_input("\n  3) Paste this CONTENT here and press a key : ")
print ("     An object Text has just been created with this pasted value of CONTENT.")


with open('PASTED.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write('')
print "\n  4) An empty file 'PASTED.txt' has just been created."
print "     Paste manually in this file the PRIM's CONTENT and shut this file."
raw_input("     --when done, press Enter to continue-- ")


print "\n  5) Enter the copy of this display of A\\rB\\nC\\r\\nD : \nA\rB\nC\r\nD"
DSP = raw_input('please, enter it on the following line :\n')
print "    An object DSP has just been created with this pasted value of this copied display"


print '\n----------'
with open('PRIM.txt','rb') as fv:
    verif = fv.read()
print "The read content of the file 'PRIM.txt' obtained by open() and read() : "+repr(verif)
print "len of the read content of the file 'PRIM.txt'  ==",len(verif)


print '\n----------'
print "The file PASTED.txt received by pasting the manually copied CONTENT of PRIM.txt"
with open('PASTED.txt','rb') as f:
    cpd = f.read()
    print "The read content of the file 'PASTED.txt' obtained by open() and read() "+\
          "is now : "+repr(cpd)
    print "its len is==",len(cpd)


print '\n----------'
print 'The object Text received through raw_input() the manually copied CONTENT of PRIM.txt'
print "value of Text=="+repr(Text)+\
      "\nText.split('\\r\\n')==",Text.split('\r\n')
print 'len of Text==',len(Text)


print '\n----------'
print "The object DSP received  through raw_input() the copy of the display of A\\rB\\nC\\r\\nD" 
print "value of DSP==",repr(DSP)
print 'len of DSP==',len(DSP)
```

My OS is Windows. I wonder if the same is observed on other operating systems.

Comment: To improve the chance that somebody might read all of that, format it so the ferschlugginer horizontal scroll bar vanishes.

Comment: Excuse me, kindall. The translation of _string of characters_ is _chaîne de caractères_ in french.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdin` is opened in text mode (you can check this by displaying `sys.stdin.mode` and seeing that it is `'r'`). If you open any file in text mode in Python, then the platform native line ending (`\r\n` for Windows) will be converted to a simple line feed (`\n`) in the Python string.

You can see this in operation by opening your `PASTED.txt` file using mode `'r'` instead of `'rb'`.

Answer (score 0):

After my post, I could look up from my code, and I indeed noticed that the modification of data copied from a file and passed to **raw_input()** is the same as the modification of newlines that Python performs when it reads data directly in a file, which is evidenced here:

```
with open("TestWindows.txt", 'wb') as f:
    f.write("PACIFIC \r  ARCTIC \n  ATLANTIC \r\n  ")

print "\n- Following string have been written in TestWindows.txt in mode 'wb' :\n"+\
      "PACIFIC \\r  ARCTIC \\n  ATLANTIC \\r\\n  "


print "\n- data got by reading the file TestWindows.txt in 'rb' mode :"
with open("TestWindows.txt", 'rb') as f:
    print "    repr(data)==",repr(f.read())

print "\n- data got by reading the file TestWindows.txt in 'r' mode :"
with open("TestWindows.txt", 'r') as f:
    print "    repr(data)==",repr(f.read())

print "\n- data got by reading the file TestWindows.txt in 'rU' mode :"
with open("TestWindows.txt", 'rU') as f:
    print "    repr(data)==",repr(f.read())
```

result:

```
- Following string have been written in TestWindows.txt in mode 'wb' :
PACIFIC \r  ARCTIC \n  ATLANTIC \r\n  

- data got by reading the file TestWindows.txt in 'rb' mode :
    repr(data)== 'PACIFIC \r  ARCTIC \n  ATLANTIC \r\n  '

- data got by reading the file TestWindows.txt in 'r' mode :
    repr(data)== 'PACIFIC \r  ARCTIC \n  ATLANTIC \n  '

- data got by reading the file TestWindows.txt in 'rU' mode :
    repr(data)== 'PACIFIC \n  ARCTIC \n  ATLANTIC \n  '
```

First, the file **PASTED.txt** has the same content as the file **PRIM.txt**, resulting from copying **PRIM.txt**'s content and pasting it in **PASTED.txt** without transiting in a Python string. So, when data goes from a file to another file transiting only by clipboard, it isn't modified. This fact proves that the content of **PRIM.txt** stands uncorrupted in the clipboard where the copying put the data.

Secondly, data going from a file to a Python string via clipboard and **raw_input()** is modified; hence the modification takes place between the clipboard and the Python string. So I thought that **raw_input()** might do the same interpretation of data received from the clipboard than the Python interpreter does  when it receives data from a reading of file.

Then, I embroidered on the idea that the replacement of **\r\n** with **\n** is due to the fact that a data of "Windows nature" becomes a data of "Python nature" and that a clipboard doesn't introduce a modification in data because it is a part under control of the Windows operating system.

Alas, the fact that data copied from the screen and passed to **raw_input()** doesn't undergo transformation of the newlines **\r\n** , despite the fact that this data transits through Windows's clipboard, breaks my tiny concept.

Then I thought that Python knows the nature of a data not because of its source, but because of information contained in the data; such information is a 'format'.  I found the following page concerning Windows's  clipboard and there are indeed several formats for the information recorded by a clipboard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648709(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe, the explanation of the modification of **\r\n** by Python is linked to these formats existing in clipboard and maybe not. But I don't understand enough all this mess and I am far to be sure.

Is anybody able to explain all the above observations ?

.

.

Thank you for your answer, ncoghlan. But I don't think it's the reason:

- **sys.stdin** has no attribute **mode**
- **sys.stdin** refers to the keyboard, as far as I undesrtand. However, in my code, data doesn't come from a typing on the keyboard but from a pasting via the clipboard. It's different.

The key point is that I don't understand how the Python interpeter could differentiates a data coming from clipboard having been copied from a file and a data coming from clipboard having been copied from the screen